# How can i use a variable to increment or decrement in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
if (something) {
  increment = 'i++'
} else {
  increment = 'i--';
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; increment) {
  ...
}
```

Obviously I cannot use a string to increment or decrement. So, what should I do instead?

Comment: what do you want with a a variable increment value? the loop heder does only match a positive increment.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a value for adding

```
for (var i = 0, offset = something ? 1 : -1; i < 10; i += offset) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Now there's a problem with the definition and condition parts, though.

Comment: I call these "delta" or "diff". Not much of an increment if it subtracts :)

Comment: @Teemu, right, but op does not offer another header for count down.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, better with `offset` now?

Comment: I guess  they will ask it quite soon after getting a crash.

Comment: @NinaScholz: ah yes, offset, much better than delta :)

Answer (score 1):

```
i += change
```

is probably the best way

But probably in most cases you can just use your original with increment and calculate the index you need, which would also work for more complicated situations i.e.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var j;
  if(something) {
    j = -i
  } else {
    j = i
  }
  // use j from here on out
}
```